# How to connect to server from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that have below code at the beginning

```
@ECHO OFF
net use x: \\server1\f$ /user:XXXXXX *
```

When I run the batch file from cmd prompt, it is asking for password, and password is successfully validated, then it is saying `System error 1219 has occurred Multiple connections to server or shared resource by same user, using more than one username is not allowed`.

But when I copy the same path from run command and press enter, then entered username and password, I am able to login into that server.

Do I need to do anything in batch file?

Comment: What do you mean by "when i copy the same path from run command and press enter"?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you're doing in the 2nd case where it works.

However, that error is caused when you connect the same network resource twice.  When you encounter the error, you already have a connection to that resource.  To avoid the error, you need to delete the connection.  You can do this by executing:

```
net use \\server1\f$ /d
```

Then try to run the batch file again.

Comment: Actually in a windows machine, we have 3 servers that shares the same username and password ,once we login into server1 , we can automatically login into server2 and server3 , now in batch script i have written first step to login into server1 and then i need to pickup log files from xxx directory in server2 and YYY directory of server3 and place in ZZZ directory in server1, but when i execute the command i am getting above error which i mentioned, but when i copy the same server path and paste in run , and do enter, i enter username and password, i am able to login,but from script giving erro

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message recently, but in a different program. It turned out to be a DNS issue, as I was able to use the IP address instead of the actual server name.

Hope this helps.

Shotty

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  As other answers have indicated, the issue for me was that I already had a connection to the server in question.

Per the response by Kevin vk on this [MSDN Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aeeb452d-0254-4bc2-a598-20f1f57ee8e0/multiple-connections-to-a-server-or-shared-resource-by-the-same-user-using-more-than-one-user-name?forum=biztalkgeneral), I used `net use` to see the existing connections that I had.  This showed me that I had a mapping that I was unaware of and was able to remove using the following command, as JohnD mentioned:

```
net use drivename: /d
```

I was then able to run my original connection command without error.  It might be worth checking to see if you have an existing connection that you're not aware of.